# AngularJS using JSONP data issue

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I have got a problem displaying content from jsonp request:

```
function ContentCtrl($scope, $http) {
"use strict";
$scope.url = 'domain/api/getposts/?auth_key=s2mEus39R296M5F6n343A3dh9c62f7cm&custom_post=updates&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
$scope.content = [];    
$scope.fetchContent = function() {
    console.log($scope.url);
    $http.get($scope.url).then(function(result){
        $scope.content = result.data;
    });
};
$scope.fetchContent();
}
```

and my html template is:

```
<div id="container" ng-controller="ContentCtrl">
<content-item ng-repeat="item in content" content="item">{{item.ID}}  
</content-item>
</div>
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Really apprecite your help...

Comment: api is returning message `Must be logged in to proceed`.

Comment: Sorry please try again

Comment: Tried to do but haven't got a clue whats wrong. Can you please help?

Comment: Code is working here. Your console.log was throwing error  http://jsfiddle.net/8Lkc6r15/1/

Comment: Why is your question code, completely different to the jsfiddle you posted?